# Comment mettre en parallèle des comparatifs en français ?

Tags: anglais, comparatifs, constructions

En anglais, on peut dire phrases en utilisant ce format :

> The sooner, the better (c'est à dire, si tu fais quelque chose plus tôt, ça sera meilleur que plus tard)
>
> The more I see you, the more I love you (c'est à dire, chaque fois que je te vois, je t'aime plus qu'avant)
>
> The fewer mistakes you make, the better your grade is (c'est à dire, si tu fais peu d'erreurs, ta note sera meilleur)

Le français a une structure similaire à celle de l'anglais?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En français c'est relativement similaire. Dans les constructions ci-dessous, les adverbes ou adjectifs de comparaison sont placés en tête, mais ils ne sont pas précédés d'un article.

> Plus je te vois, plus je t'aime.
>
> Moins tu fais de fautes, meilleure sera ta note.

Cela ne fonctionne que lorsqu'on corrèle des propositions entières. Lorsque, comme dans le premier exemple, l'anglais juxtapose des adjectifs ou des adverbes substantivés, le français a tendance à recourir aux superlatifs (qui sont aussi des substantifs) et les lie par un verbe.

> Le plus tôt sera le mieux.

*Être* n'est pas le seul choix, mais malheureusement ce n'est pas toujours possible de construire une phrase sensée de cette façon. Il est généralement préférable de construire des propositions entières. Par exemple, « *The taller, the better* » peut devenir :

> Plus on/il/elle est grand(e), mieux c'est.

ou, si l'on parle d'architecture (un exemple comme un autre) :

> Plus c'est grand, mieux c'est.

---

French is relatively similar. In the following constructions, comparison adverbs or comparison adjectives come first, but no article is added.

> Plus je te vois, plus je t'aime.
>
> Moins tu fais de fautes, meilleure sera ta note.

Though it only works when correlating full clauses. When, as in your first example, English juxtaposes substantiated adjectives or adverbs, French tends to use superlatives (which also are substantives) and they are linked to one another with a verb instead:

> Le plus tôt sera le mieux.

*Être* isn't the only choice but it's unfortunately not always possible to build a meaningful sentence like this. It's generally wise to build up clauses instead. For instance, “*The taller, the better*” may become:

> Plus on/il/elle est grand(e), mieux c'est.

or if speaking about architecture (for example):

> Plus c'est grand, mieux c'est.