# When to use possessive vs article, e.g. "mettre le réveil" vs "mettre mon réveil" ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, déterminants, possessif

I am not sure which of these is more natural, to say *j'ai mis mon réveil* or to say *j'ai mis le réveil*. For all I know both work, or one sounds less natural, I do not know.

I actually have this problem with a lot of phrases. I know in French you use "le" to refer to body parts and clothing where in English we would use a possessive, i.e. "Show me your hand" -> "Fais voir le main."

But I'm not sure how many other things this applies to.

Comment: “Il se lave les mains”, “Il l'a dans la main”, but… in this case… “Montre-moi ta main”. Hard to tell why.

Comment: REALLY??? Oh my god, the *one* example I choose. F*** that. Sigh thanks.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I think it's because there are two people involved, so we need to specify whose hand it is.

Comment: My god, that would actually make *sense* and be perfectly usable in practice as a rule. Could it *be* that straightforward?

Comment: @Aerovistae I think the question is "Do I have to specify the owner ?". If you say "montre-moi la main", it may be ambigous, because there are YOUR hands and HIS/HER hands in the universe... Whereas if you are teaching a kid what is a hand, you can say "Montre moi la main" because you don't care if (s)he shows yours or his/hers. Don't you agree ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may already know that you use possesive to say mine, yours etc., and definite article to say the. So it is up to you if you want to say set I set MY alarm clock or set I set THE alarm clock.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does help a bit! Just trying to determine whether it's the same as in English, where you can really use either and both sound normal. Welcome to French.SE by the way! I'm glad we are getting new users recently. It was just like 10 of us for so long.

Comment: One month counts as new :)

Answer (score 4):

S'il s'agit de mon propre réveil : « J'ai mis mon réveil » (ou plutôt « j'ai mis mon réveil à sonner », ou « j'ai réglé mon réveil pour 6h30 », etc.). « J'ai mis le réveil (à sonner) » est possible, mais je n'ai pas tendance à le dire.

S'il s'agit d'un réveil commun à plusieurs personnes, par exemple pour un couple : « j'ai mis le réveil à sonner » (et pas « j'ai mis notre réveil », c'est parfaitement compréhensible mais je ne le dirais pas, sauf s'il y a vraiment une ambiguïté (« j'ai mis notre réveil pour 6h30 et celui du gamin pour 7h »)).

Plus il y a de distance entre l'objet et la personne, moins on a tendance à utiliser l'adjectif possessif. Par exemple, même en vivant seul, je ne me vois pas dire « j'ai mis ma machine à laver en route ».

Il peut y avoir une nuance de sens, d'insistance ou d'usage. Par exemple les deux phrases suivantes sont possibles :

> Quelqu'un a frappé à la porte.
>   Quelqu'un a frappé à ma porte.

On utiliserait plutôt « la » s'il est clair d'après le contexte de quelle porte il s'agit, et « ma » s'il faut le préciser.

La principale différence avec l'anglais, c'est pour les parties du corps. Là, si la phrase parle clairement d'une personne donnée, on utilise presque toujours un article défini (ou indéfini) et pas un adjectif possessif.

> Je me lave les mains.   (I'm washing my hands.)
>   Je m'en lave les mains.   (I wash my hands of it.)
>   Il a un poil dans la main.   (Lit. there's a hair on his hand; fig. he's lazy.)
>   Il a la jambe cassée.   (His leg is broken.)
>   Il a une jambe cassée.   (He has a broken leg.)
>   Elle a la tête sur les épaules.   (Lit. she has a head on her shoulders; fig. she's level-headed.)
>   Ils ont été pris la main dans le sac.   (Lit. they were caught with their hands in the bag; fig. they were caught red-handed.)
>   Elles ont les oreilles qui sifflent.   (Lit. their ears are whistling; fig. someone is talking about them in their absence.)

Par contre, lorsque plusieurs personnes sont mentionnées et qu'elles ne sont pas toutes concernées, l'adjectif possessif revient.

> Montre-moi ta main.

Même avec une seule personne, il y a quelques exceptions.

> Elle porte son enfant sur ses épaules.
>   Le danseur passe ses jambes l'une devant l'autre.

Comment: The third paragraph, the sentence using "Plus il y a de distance entre l'objet et la personne, moins on a tendance à...." I understand exactly what it means but it is grammatically foreign to me. That's idiomatic? I would have thought it would be "Le plus que..., le moins que..." Maybe that's just me giving in to a desire to translate literally from English.

Comment: @Aerovistae: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/comment-mettre-en-parall%c3%a8le-des-comparatifs-en-fran%c3%a7ais