# Traduction de "The more vegetables you eat"

Tags: grammaire, articles

> The more vegetables you eat, the better it is for your health.

Quelle serait la bonne traduction de cette phrase ?

> Plus tu manges de légumes, mieux c'est pour ta santé.

Est-il correct d'utiliser "**de** légumes" et non pas "**des** légumes", car il s'agit de "plus de légumes" ?

Comment: La question donné dans le titre à déjà été posée ici: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/comment-mettre-en-parall%c3%a8le-des-comparatifs-en-fran%c3%a7ais. Ce serait mieux si le titre reflétait le fait que le sujet de la question c'est *de* / *des*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Plus tu manges **de** légumes, mieux c'est pour **la** santé.

The *separated* construction in the first part comes from "plus **de** légumes", not "plus des légumes".

On a side note: I'd rather place the definite article "la" before "santé".

Answer (score 2):

Il faudrait plutôt traduire par :

> Plus tu manges de légumes, **meilleur** c'est pour **ta** santé.

Mieux est le comparatif de bien. 
Cette voiture est bien, mais celle ci est mieux.

Meilleur est le comparatif de bon. 
Ce plat est bon, mais celui ci est meilleur.

Ici on dit que les légumes sont bons à la santé (et non pas bien à la santé), donc on préférera meilleur.

Je mettrai "meilleur pour **TA** santé", parce que la phrases s'adresse à "tu". Donc on reste sur le même sujet: tu manges ... ta santé.

Comment: C'est en effet plus "juste", mais la version avec *mieux* est plus courante. A choisir en fonction du registre de language, donc.